# Are Steam account names private?

Tags: steam

From what I gathered, there are **four** kinds of identifiers on *Steam*:

- Account name
- Account email
- Profile name
- Steam Community name

I have my real name in my account name and email, and I would like to keep it private. My profile name is what I would like others to see.

My question is do others (including your friends on *Steam*) see your account name or email?

Comment: I think there are only three, aren't "account name" and "profile name" the same?

Comment: @user598527 no they are not. Account name is the username you use to login. Profile name can be different from this.

Comment: the google crawl of my steam page shows my real name, so my steam profile page must be showing it to everyone. And I can't figure out how to turn it off or remove my real name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question Steam **account** names are private. Your email is private too as it is needed should you ever donate.
Below you can see the highest  Steam Level player's information according to [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/).
[image: St4ck's account information]

This is the most information you can get about someone's account without having to ask said person.

Comment: I can corroborate that the login ID and  your profile name are different. Mine have always been different. It's also true that the profile names need not be unique. There are hundreds+ users with the same profile name as me.

Answer (score -1):

Steam account names are private, unless you capture it on camera or something like that. Or your profile name is the same as your steam account name, it remains private.